# Email-only authentication in Node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication

I am currently developing an application using a MERN stack, and I'd like to have authentication for it as well. However, before I just install PassportJS, I'd like to know how I should approach authentication. Should my client-side send my server a POST request with the email address in plaintext in the POST body? Should it encrypt it beforehand? Do I store the encrypted email address in MongoDB, or the plaintext version? I'm not asking for the best practice, but rather the approaches that could be taken given my current stack. I would like to understand this without just installing a package and calling the job done.

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt the email ? Do you mean email only authentication like [auth0 passwordless](https://auth0.com/passwordless) ?

Comment: Yeah. I'm not really familiar with authentication, so I figure I need to encrypt something, no? What motivates people to encrypt a password but not an email address?

Comment: Because you often need the email address to send users an email.

Comment: So putting an email address in persistent storage as cleartext is an acceptable practice?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the middleware of passport inside your routes before calling your custom callback and defines passport with the great configuration